# Viewing QuartzScheduler MBeans from JConsole

Tags: quartz-scheduler, jmx, jconsole

I would like to see and manage Quartz Scheduler from JConsole. I configured the quartz props.

```
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export=true
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.registryPort=1099
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.createRegistry=true
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.registryHost=localhost
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck=true
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority=5
```

But I am not able to connect the jconsole using the url

```
service:jmx:rmi://localhost/jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
```

Please help.

Answer (score 5):

See http://jira.opensymphony.com/browse/QUARTZ-300

You need Quartz 1.6 and commons-modeler in your classpath. The add

```
org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export=true
```

in your quartz configuration.

Comment: You may also want to set the property org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.objectName

Comment: @jhouse +1 actually, your suggestion was essential in order for it to work using Spring 3.1 + Quartz 1.6.1